# OnActivityResult the intent rutrn null value coming back from CropIntent

Tags: android, image

**When i try to use camera and get that images and try to crop using cropintent
but after returning from CropIntent In OnActivityResult the intent value is showing null**

On the Dialog i use camera the dialog code is here

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File file=null;
                    try {

                        file = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("File creation","Error occured during file creation");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);


                dialog.dismiss();
```

the OnActivityReultCode is

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    String path="";
    switch (requestCode) {


    case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && !currentPhotopath.isEmpty()){


             mImageCaptureUri = intent.getData();
            Log.e("Camera path","" +path);
            Log.e("Camera uri",mImageCaptureUri.toString());*/

               performCrop();


        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error occured",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        break;


    case PIC_CROP:

           Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
           Bitmap bp = extras.getParcelable("data");
           photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        break;

    default:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not load image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
```

**And the performCrop method is**

```
private void performCrop()
{
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(mImageCaptureUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP );

}
```

Comment: The requestCode is PICK_FROM_FILE, and your switch refer to PICK_FROM_CAMERA?

Comment: it was by mistake in posting code sorry for that

Comment: Did you defined LaunchMode of activity in manifest?

Comment: lauch mode be single task ??

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score 0):

There is times that there is issues with the `launchMode`. Try use:

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: it still shows the error 08-23 06:14:07.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=33, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.colors.notepad/com.colors.notepad.PhotoScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You get null somewhere inside the onActivityResult. add checks to prevents this. Check in debugger what happens exatcly

Comment: the mImageCaptureUri is returning null

Comment: So you need to check why.